# Override OneDrive accounts GET response with Azure

Tags: azure, onedrive

Is it possible to intercept GET requests to my personal consumer OneDrive account, tied to an E-Mail Account, like "happy@hotmail.com" with Azure? The one that is used with Windows 8/10 Desktop/Phone?
The idea is that the Azure service responses the GET requests for files / file-listings with its own file/file-list so that it reflects the files stored at a completely different space.

All I can see are ways doing that with services running under like account...azure-something.com, which is completely useless for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in capability in Azure to do something like this. Not sure what you're trying to build/accomplish here, but, if you wanted to intercept OneDrive's calls, you would need to:

1. Create an HTTP proxy application on the local machine that would intercept the calls being made by the OneDrive client.
2. Instead of forwarding those calls to the OneDrive server, forward them to your Azure service.
3. Build and maintain an Azure service that implemented all of the APIs used by OneDrive's app to a high enough degree of fidelity that the app would continue to work as expected with your custom data source. This includes things like authentication, REST APIs, configuration, etc.
4. Maintain this service as the OneDrive clients are upgraded and add new/changed functionality.

In short, it's not easy and something that would take a ton of work just to get going, and would likely be a source of continued bugs that are hard/impossible to debug since you can't know what the client is doing.

If you are looking for a way to sync files between a service and Windows, it would undoubtedly be easier to build your own sync app that communicates with the backend storage service you want to use, instead of trying to get OneDrive's app to do it for you. Then you would have control (and source code) for both the client and server pieces, and ensure they always worked together properly.

Comment: The idea is to process the GET of course after the login barrier has been passed. A similar thing is already possible with "Logic Apps". There you can for example trigger a process after an image was uploaded. What I'm searching for is a mechanism which responses to a file listing / request call with its own content. And I would want to respond only to selective GET requests with custom code, e.g. picture requests.